# UISwitch not displaying in custom UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I need a custom `cell` with a `label` and a `switch`.
Now, the main problem is that I can't get the `switch` to display. I have tried several methods, including adding the `switch` programatically to the cell's `accessoryView`.

I used the IB, added the `switch` to the cell, connected the `IBOutlet`. I also tried to add the `switch` programatically, in cell's `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    if (!self.fieldSwitch) {
        self.fieldSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        [self.fieldSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchUpdatedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        self.fieldSwitch.onTintColor = [ColorManager sharedInstance].genericSwitchColor;
        self.accessoryView = self.fieldSwitch;
    }
}
```

This has had absolutely no effect; I also tried adding it as a subview to the cell's `contentView` then calling `bringSubviewToFront:`. Again, no success.

I checked, and `self`, `accessoryView`, `fieldSwitch` none of them were `nil`.

Does anyone have any idea what could be so wrong? on a side note, does anyone understand why adding a control from the `IB` is broken by default?

Comment: Did you try to add it in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: yes, and nothing changes.
What is more frustrating is that I don't understand how come controls added from IB are not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using size classes you have to set a constraint for the UISwitch. For example if you are using an Any Any size class and you place the UISwitch in the cell it may actually be displaying far off to the right. (I would of posted this as a comment however not enough rep)

Comment: You were right. The `tableView` was placed inside a UIViewController, and forgot to pin the `tableView` edges to the `superview` edges.